# What is usable latency for ssh and RDP?

Tags: ssh, remote-desktop, latency

What is usable latency for ssh and Windows Remote Desktop Connection (RDP)?

By usable, I mean for things like editing text through a text editor over ssh or RDP so that the latency wouldn't drive the person nuts and/or significantly hamper productivity.

It seems hard to simulate different latency speeds so if anyone could share some experience with a latency that was too much (or ideally a latency that was just bearable), I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I live in Europe and have few linux servers in diffrent locations.

Frankfurt:

30-100ms ping, working with SSH is comfortable

Amsterdam:

200-300ms ping - SSH is not very comfortable, but it's possible to work

New York:

500-1000ms ping - forget SSH with latency like this, typing 10 character word takes 5-10 secods

I have no experience with RDP on "far servers", but I guess it would be similar to ssh.

For NY server (500ms+ ping) - I write bash scripts or just commands in notepad on my laptop and paste them into SSH.

Comment: Seems strange the ping is 10 times worse from Frankfurt to Amsterdam (about 450 km). It's entirely possible to get 30-100 ms pings to any major city from another.

Comment: Yea, I was thinking about this. I guess it is my server provider fault. I haven't tried to ping from Frankfurt server to Amsterdam server...

Comment: anyway, +1 for the posting the experience at different pings

Answer (score 2):

Above 400ms isn't very comfortable; working around in VIm and typing commands is a huge pain, and correcting a typo 20 chars back takes at least 30 seconds.

Comment: Yea, typos are painful in slow SSH :)